# QuickBooks Desktop Integration via .Net

Tags: .net, desktop, quickbooks

We have written a .Net program that communicates with QuickBooks Desktop via RequestProcessor2() . It runs periodically. The program runs fine but each time it runs it seems to create a Windows Process entry called 'QuickBooks Automatic Update'. The list keeps growing the more often the program runs. I was wondering if anyone knows why this is happening and maybe how to stop it as it seems to cause issues with QuickBooks after a couple of days. We could terminate that process after a run but before we go down that route I would like to understand first what it is and why it creates these entries each time.

Connect to QuickBooks:

```
            // Create the session manager object using QBFC
            sessionManager = new RequestProcessor2();

            sessionManager.OpenConnection("", "ABCD QuickBooks Interface");
            
            // set Auth Preferences
            var prefs = sessionManager.AuthPreferences;
            prefs.PutUnattendedModePref(QBXMLRPUnattendedModePrefType.umpRequired);

            Ticket = sessionManager.BeginSession(QuickBooksCompanyFile, QBFileMode.qbFileOpenMultiUser);
```

Disconnect:

```
                sessionManager.EndSession(Ticket);
                sessionManager.CloseConnection();
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What is QuickBooks Desktop?

Comment: Can you provide a code that you use?

Comment: I have added the code and yes it is QuickBooks Desktop I am connecting to.